# Rails 3.2 - Application Controller + Devise Current_user Issue

Tags: authentication, devise, mime-types, cancan, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two roles defined in my User Model:

```
User.role == admin
or
User.role == basic
```

In my **Application Controller**:

```
include MobilizedController
```

In **lib/mobilized_controller.rb**:

```
module MobilizedController
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :set_basic_request, :if => :basic_logged_in?
  end 

  private

  def set_basic_request
    request.format = :basic
    prepend_view_path "app/views/basic"
  end 

  def basic_logged_in?
    current_user.role == 'basic'
  end 
end
```

This is all fine when I am logged in, it sets the Mime Type correctly and renders my basic views.
Unfortunately, when I'm not logged in I get:

> Undefined method 'role' for nil:NilClass

which I guess means that the current_user is not set, and thus calling nil on it won't work.

Does anyone have any suggestion for this? I need to be able to render the default log in page if a user is not logged in, and then set the Mime Type on login.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In your example for basic_logged_in you set current_user.role to basic. It seems like you do not set a role for admin or not-logged in users.

So current_user.role is not set if you are not logged in or login as admin.